How to pronounce Jiong using American phonics?
Jiong, how to pronounce it using American phonetics?

I suspect this will be considered off-topic (there is a Chinese SE which I'm not familiar with the rules of). And it's not clear if you're an American wanting to pronounce Chinese or a Chinese person seeking to give a pronunciation guide to Americans. If the former, your best bet is to ask someone how their name should be pronounced. There's no universal set of rules, although you'll find a lot of guides on pronunciation aimed at English-speakers, some more accurate than others. Often pinyin "j" is approximated by /dʒ/ (as, rather confusingly, is "zh").

See also https://www.howtopronounce.com/jiong

Are you asking about 囧 (Chinese internet emoticon that resembles a sad face)? A native English speaker get pretty close (to my ears) just guessing from 'jiong' but the tone will be neutral or first tone not 3rd. I don't think there's another common character with that pronunciation. Maybe could be confused with 姜 (ginger) jiang.

In a comment, Stuart F wrote:

I suspect this will be considered off-topic (there is a Chinese SE which I'm not familiar with the rules of). And it's not clear if you're an American wanting to pronounce Chinese or a Chinese person seeking to give a pronunciation guide to Americans. If the former, your best bet is to ask someone how their name should be pronounced. There's no universal set of rules, although you'll find a lot of guides on pronunciation aimed at English-speakers, some more accurate than others. Often pinyin "j" is approximated by /dʒ/ (as, rather confusingly, is "zh").

